# Android : Converting data from date,time picker from Calendar to sql Timestamp and reverse.

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, timestamp

I am working on an Android application in which I would like to persist the date and time entered by the user in java.sql.timestamp and save it. When again displaying to the user, I would like to convert it back to format like "dd-MM-YYYY" and "HH:MM", separately. I managed to set the entries recieved from the user to year, month, day, hour, minute in separate variables, and even tried getting the time, but Calendar instance always returns me the current date and time. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Kindly let me know.

Android code :

```
 Button menuStartDate, menuStartTime;
 EditText startDateTextField, startTimeTextField;
    int monthOfYear, dayOfWeek, hourOfADay, minuteOfHour, year;
private Calendar startCalendar;
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == menuStartDate) {

            startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            monthOfYear = startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfWeek = startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            startDateTextField.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, year, monthOfYear, dayOfWeek);
            datePickerDialog.show();
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfWeek);

        }
        if (view == menuStartTime) {

            startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            hourOfADay = startCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minuteOfHour = startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            startTimeTextField.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, hourOfADay, minuteOfHour, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfADay);
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfHour);
        }
```

As you can see in the above instance, I am getting the information from user, and setting it. Unfortunately, I am not able to get the time set by user in Calendar. Here is the code for conversion :

```
if(view == submitMenuButton){
            MenuCard menuCard = new MenuCard();
            if(!(startDateTextField.getText().toString().length()<1)){
                    if(!(startTimeTextField.getText().toString().length()<1)){
                        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(startCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
                        Log.d("TImestamp is",timestamp.toString());

                    } else {
                        startTimeTextField.setError("Please select start time");
                    }
            }else {
                startDateTextField.setError("Please select start date");

            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: then use dateformatter and split sqlite date into date and time separately using two different formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to set the Date of DatePickerDialog:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    // dd.MM.yyyy
    register_textview_birthday.setText(dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year);
  }
}, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

And the code to retrieve it as java.util.Date:

```
public static Date stringToDate(String string, final String format, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
  ThreadLocal formater = new ThreadLocal() {
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
      return new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);
    }
  };
  return ((SimpleDateFormat)formater.get()).parse(string);
}

Date date = stringToDate(register_textview_birthday.getText().toString().trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now you can convert your java.util.Date to sql Timestamp.
Change the date format and locale according to yours.

Beware of SimpleDateFormat being not thread-safe.
So use the TreadLocal like i did in the code above.

For the time: append the date string from DatePicker with the time string from TimerPicker and change the format to something like "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm".

Comment: But I also have time in the other picker, where I want to save the time in timestamp as well.

Comment: Append both date and time to one string. String dateTime = DATE_FROM_DATEPCIKER + " " + TIME_FROM_TIMEPICKER; Date date = stringToDate(dateTime, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM", Locale.getDefault()); The sql date (and time) you can get via: new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());